# How to change Double Quote(") to &quot; in TinyMce Editor?

Tags: javascript, ruby, tinymce

I am using TinyMce Editor , I am having an issue whenever i am using double quotes it breaks my code because In the HTML source of TinyMce it shows " where it should show the &quot in the source , that means it is not converting " to " like it does for & to &amp

I would like to know , how to covert the " to &quot when i am clicking on the HTML source link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TinyMCE likes to clean & format things for you. The behavior you are describing could be the result of TinyMCE's "entity_encoding" or "cleanup" options.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:cleanup

My bet would be that you want to change the "entity_encoding" property to "named" or "raw" depending on what you are trying to accomplish.